# How to dynamically render Vue.js directives in custom Django template tags

Tags: html, django, vuejs2, django-templates, vue-directives

I created a custom template tag in Django called `text_field`

```py
@register.inclusion_tag('form_field_tags/text_field.html')
def text_field(field, prefix=None, field_type=None, attr=None, **kwargs):
    return {
        'field': field,
        'prefix': prefix,
        'field_type': field_type,
        'placeholder': '',
        'attrs': parse_attrs(attr)
    }
```

Where `parse_attrs` is a function that takes as input something like this  `class=form-control mb-4, v-model=property_name`.

```html
 {% text_field form.property_name attr="class=form-control mb-4, v-model=property_name" %}
```

`parse_attrs` then create a dictionary of HTML attribute and value that can be looped over, so in my `text_field.html` i can loop over all the `attrs` passed in from the `text_field` custom template tag

```html
<label >
    {% if field.field.required %}
    <strong> {{ field.label }} <span> * </span> </strong>
    {% else %}
      {{ field.label }}
    {% endif %}
</label>
  <input
          {% if field_type == "password" %}
              type="password"
          {% else %}
              type="text"
          {% endif %}
          {% for attr, val in attrs.items %}
          {{ attr }} = {{ val }}
          {% endfor %}
          name="{% if prefix %}{{prefix}}-{% endif %}{{ field.name }}"
          placeholder="{{ placeholder }}"
          id="{% if prefix %}{{prefix}}-{% endif %}{{ field.name }}"
          {% if field.field.required %}
          required="required"
          {% endif %}
          {% if field.value %}
          value="{{ field.value }}"
          {% endif %}>
```

However, when I try to refresh the browser and see the rendered output what I get is

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control mb-4" name="property_name" placeholder="" id="property_name" required="required">
```

instead of this

```html
<input type="text" v-model="property_name" class="form-control mb-4" name="property_name" placeholder="" id="property_name" required="required">
```

Any thoughts on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I realized that the browser I was using (Firefox Dev) wasn't showing the `v-model` directive when viewed with the browser inspector nevertheless if you look at the HTML that gets sent in the browser through the network tab, the `v-model` directive is definitely there so Vue.js would recognize it.